# How to get file transfer speed with axios in real time?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, axios, file-transfer

I wondered how can one build the indicator of upload speed like what we see in google drive or any other service. I know axios has `onUploadProgress` options which can help us to build progress bar. But how to use it to show actual transfer speed for every second in real time.

Comment: Check this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54213601/how-to-show-progress-of-axios-during-get-request-not-download-or-upload]

Comment: That's not I want to know. I want to understand how to get transfer speed not the progress bar.